# Infinite positions in 3D chomp

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, ordinal-numbers, infinite-games

I've recently come back to investigating ordinal chomp. See [A winning move for the first player in $3 \times 3 \times \omega$ Ordinal Chomp](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226124/a-winning-move-for-the-first-player-in-3-times-3-times-omega-ordinal-chomp) for a definition. I made a new discovery, that the position \begin{pmatrix}\omega&\omega&1 \\ \omega&\omega&1 \\ 2&0&0\end{pmatrix} is a losing position, first by a computer search, then by a proof showing that all possible moves from this position are winning (I can outline the proof on request). It seems like positions like this (I call them quadruple $\omega$ positions) are extremely rare, and I haven't been able to find another example so far.

My question is: Are there other quadruple $\omega$ positions in $3 \times 3 \times \omega$ chomp, and if so, what are they?